# Dynamically set height of element in order to make it overflow: auto?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, overflow

I have a long list of elements which I would like to scroll while keeping the rest of the page static around it.

```
<header>
  <!-- the header is stuck to the top of the page -->
</header>
<ul class="list">
  <!-- long list of stuff which should scroll -->
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <!-- ... and so on, hundreds of elements -->
</ul>
<footer>
  <!-- the footer is stuck to the bottom of the page -->
</footer>
```

Now this seems to work as long as I set a height on the `<ul>`.

```
ul.list {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 700px;
}
```

The problem is that if the user's browser is taller than `700px + [header height] + [footer height]` then `ul.list` won't take up all of it's available space. There is a gap between the list an the footer. Conversely, if the user's browser is smaller than `700px`, some of the list elements are hidden off the bottom of the page.

How can I make the list take up all of the available height?

The only way I can think of so far is to detect the `$header.offset()` and `$footer.offset()`, subtract them to get the distance between them and set the height of the `ul` everytime the window `resize` event is triggered. This seems like an overly complicated solution to what seems like it should be a simple problem. Is there a better way?

By the way, this is the styling I have applied to make the fotter stick to the bottom of the page.

```
footer  {
  // stick the footer to the bottom of the page
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know know the height of the header and footer and can absolutely position the list, it's simple enough:

```
ul.list {
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top:    [height of header]px;
  bottom: [height of footer]px;
}
```

If you want the list to have a fixed width, and keep it centered, you can do:

```
ul.list {
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top:    [height of header]px;
  bottom: [height of footer]px;

  left:  50%;      
  width: 600px;  /* as an example */
  margin-left: -300px; /* negative half of the width */
}
```

Comment: @JakeParis: Thanks, although that's a very different solution than my answer. [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/W69fV/2/) that uses the code in the answer (i.e. absolute positioning, etc.)